# Ways to unlock iPhone 5 with iOS 10 to reduce Home button presses

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone 5 and since I installed iOS 10 I have to press home button twice to unlock the screen. I hate having to do this. I feel that there is 200%  probability more than before that my home button breaks. Is there any other way to unlock the screen? Is it possible to go back to the 'Slide to unlock'? I would also hate to put the Assistive Touch button on the screen.

Comment: I presume by "the button" you mean Assistive Touch. Feel free to [edit] further.

Comment: You can turn on your iPhone with the power button, then swipe to the widgets screen, then press one of the app icons there to unlock without pressing the home button a single time.

Comment: @owlswipe Thanks!. That is a good one that I did not know. It still sucks anyway :)

Comment: @NicoRiff You're welcome! It still sucks indeed :).

Answer (score 2):

You can't use Slide to Unlock without jailbreaking. Since your device does not have Touch ID, you can't use Rest to Unlock either, and your device does not support Raise to Wake either.

One way to reduce the wear on your home button is to use the power button to wake the device, then press the home button when you actually wish to unlock the device.

Comment: Yes I´ve been looking for workarounds but I still cannot believe that Apple guys removed the slide to unlock feature. They should, unless leave it as an optional or accesibility feature. Thanks.

Comment: @NicoRiff They must have only been thinking of the more recent devices with the introduction of the feature. With Raise to Wake, it makes sense… with Touch ID, it *mostly* makes sense… without either of these features it's quite an annoyance.

Comment: With TouchID, it's actually rather nice, and I believe that this is a way to push people to a newer phone (meaning they probably won't add slide to unlock back)